# Ionic App not running on ios/Android but working on browser

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I developed an app that was working perfectly on Ionic DevApp on my iPhone. Suddenly it stopped working. I even tested a new blank app and it does not work. I tested on many wifi and 3G signals and also on an Android phone but it does not work!

On my **iPhone** I’m getting the following **error**:

> Unable to load page. The request timed out.

On the **Android** phone I got this **error**:

> error err_connection_timed_out.

I **tried** running the following, but none worked:

1. `ionic serve`
2. `ionic serve -c`
3. `ionic serve -c --no-proxy`

Running `ionic info` gives me:

> Ionic:
>
> ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.5.0 (C:\Users\rodri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
>   Ionic Framework : ionic-angular 3.9.2
>   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0
>
> Cordova:
>
> cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
>   Cordova Platforms : android 7.1.2, ios 4.5.5
>   Cordova Plugins : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.2.3, (and 5 other plugins)
>
> System:
>
> NodeJS : v10.13.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
>   npm : 6.4.1
>   OS : Windows 10

**EDIT:**

I tried running `ionic repair` which gives me this error:

> shell.js: internal error
>   Error: ETIMEDOUT: connection timed out, read
>
> [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
>
> cordova prepare exited with exit code 1.

Comment: can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

It was just a Firewall coming from McAfee Firewall blocking the port I needed. Just had to open the port on the McAfee app.